# Repeat changing value in single column in a dataframe n times using dplyr

Tags: dplyr

I am using `dplyr` to manipulate and tidy up a data frame and need to repeat a specific value in one of the columns 3 more times (4 in total). It is just a single column of the dataframe that needs to edited and I am not sure how to do this with the `mutate` function.

```
current_column = c(69886, 1, 1, 1, 38866, 1, 1, 1)
desired_column = c(69886, 69886, 69886, 69886, 38866, 38866, 38866, 38866)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to replicate values in R. Without more context it is difficult to be sure exactly which approach will be better.

Depending on your setup, you may be able to use the `rep` function. For example:

```r
df = data.frame(desired_column = c(rep(69886, 4), rep(38866, 4)))
```

If there are other columns in your data frame these could be used to group the data together. For example:

```r
df = data.frame(groups = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                current_column = c(69886, 1, 1, 1, 38866, 1, 1, 1))

df = df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  mutate(desired_column = max(current_column))
```

But if neither of these are an option, then the best I can propose is looping through the table. Note that this approach is dependent on order of the rows in the data frame, if the order of the rows changes, then this method will fail.

```r
current_value = NA

# loop through all rows
for(ii in 1:nrow(df)){
  # if value in this row is not 1, record this value
  if(df$current_column[ii] != 1){
    current_value = df$current_column[ii]
  # if value in this row is 1, overwrite this value
  } else {
    df$current_column[ii] = current_value
  }
}
```

If you really want a dplyr solution, the following is less efficient but does something similar to the immediately above:

```r
df = data.frame(current_column = c(69886, 1, 1, 1, 38866, 1, 1, 1))

df = df %>% mutate(new_col = current_column)

for(ii in 1:10){ # this will replace up to 10 following 1's, increase this number if there are more 1's
  df = df %>%
    mutate(lag_col = lag(new_col)) %>%
    mutate(new_col = ifelse(new_col == 1, lag_col, new_col)) %>%
    select(current_column, new_col, desired_column)
}
```